# A question about the use of the subjunctive mood

Tags: irrealis-were

What is the difference between these two sentences and which one is correct? If both be correct, when should I use the one over the other?

"If people who seek food **were able** to produce enough food by themselves, they would no longer need help."

"If people who seek food **were to be able** to produce enough food by themselves, they would no longer need help."

Comment: To quote Barrie England, '... in a sentence such as _If I were you, I’d have a haircut,_ many grammarians still regard this use of _were_ as subjunctive. Huddleston and Pullum do not. They call it _irrealis were_.' [trimmed]

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence:

**If people who seek food were to be able to produce enough food by themselves, they would no longer need help.**

makes no sense to me. For me, "to be" adds only confusion, not nuance. However, I have heard, often enough, "were to be" plus a past participle, and in those (passive construction) cases it does make sense:

**If people who seek food *were to be given* the wherewithal to produce food for themselves, they would no longer need to be given food.**

although even there the "to be" adds nothing and could be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

The second phrase is incorrect: "to be" plus the infinitive implies a degree of compulsion that is not needed in this sentence.

Comment: I wonder if the second sentence is grammatical.

Comment: @CopperKettle I'm not too happy with it; 'were to be' is normally followed by an -ed form and can imply intention or requirement (as Martin implies) or unmarked 'future in the past'. 'The prawns were to be eaten before Friday.' / '[It was a great place to look.] The children were to find nine different beetles in that particular field.' I suppose 'were to be' can be used as a deleted form of 'were supposed / intended to be' _or_ 'were going to be': 'The upstairs carpets were to be green.'

Comment: 'Were to' followed by the infinitive does not always imply a degree of compulsion: "If he were to arrive tomorrow ..." has a very similar meaning to "If he arrived tomorrow ...". I think that 'if X were to be able to' is not so much incorrect as inelegant. As 'If X were able to' is  available, the 'to' in the 'were to' version *seems* redundant. There are five citations for 'were to be able to' in **if** clauses in COCA, suggesting that I am not alone in finding it acceptable.

Comment: I afree, my answer was hasty and I did not stop to think abiut "were I to do this" etc.